# http request sent multiple times randomly, IP address changes between (Iphone Safari)

Tags: forms, http, email, post, request

I am having a strange problem occuring (seemingly) random. I have a basic POST-form, which sends the inserted data to a specified email. The same form is in use for several sites, and this problem occurs very rarely.

The problem: **sometimes the exact same post request is sent multiple times, causing the exact same email to be sent multiple times.** The html form is basic, it doesn't use ajax etc. for sending.

What makes this problem interesting, is the fact that the **resends occur VERY randomly, usually days apart!** Our customer has now redirected us the same form sent six times, spanning over three days! So, we can rule out the client refreshing the page (which obviously would cause the form to be sent several times).

PS. When the problem was first discovered, I added a session to check whether the same form has been sent, but that didn't solve the problem. So perhaps the sessions are also renewed between sends.

The latest sending spree was done via IPHONE, I will attach the logs below. I am not sure if the previous were done via Iphone, but I have never managed to replicate the problem when sending a form via Desktop browser. What makes this case even more interesting, is the fact that the **IP Addresses change in between requests.** I checked the IP:s and three of them are from **different network providers!**

**The logs (there were also several GET -requests before these posts, as if the page was loaded several times):**

`xx.xx.xx.xx1 = first IP, Network provider: DNA Oy xx.xxx.xxx.xx2 = second IP, Network provider: DNA Oy xx.xxx.xxx.xx3 = third IP, Network provider: Elisa Oyj xxx.xx.xxx.xx4 = fourth IP, Network provider: TeliaSonera Finland Oyj`

actual domain changed to [www.MYDOMAIN.fi](http://www.MYDOMAIN.fi)

```
xx.xx.xx.xx1 - - [17/May/2023:15:17:04 +0300] "POST /tyomatkustus-ryhmat/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8921 "https://www.MYDOMAIN.fi/tyomatkustus-ryhmat/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.2 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"

xx.xx.xx.xx1 - - [17/May/2023:17:09:49 +0300] "POST /tyomatkustus-ryhmat/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8979 "https://www.MYDOMAIN.fi/tyomatkustus-ryhmat/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.2 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"

xx.xx.xx.xx1 - - [18/May/2023:07:30:44 +0300] "POST /tyomatkustus-ryhmat/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8981 "https://www.MYDOMAIN.fi/tyomatkustus-ryhmat/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.2 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"

xx.xxx.xxx.xx2 - - [18/May/2023:17:36:56 +0300] "POST /tyomatkustus-ryhmat/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8979 "https://www.MYDOMAIN.fi/tyomatkustus-ryhmat/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.2 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"

xx.xxx.xxx.xx2 - - [18/May/2023:19:25:36 +0300] "POST /tyomatkustus-ryhmat/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8979 "https://www.MYDOMAIN.fi/tyomatkustus-ryhmat/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.2 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"

xx.xxx.xxx.xx3 - - [19/May/2023:21:38:01 +0300] "POST /tyomatkustus-ryhmat/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8979 "https://www.MYDOMAIN.fi/tyomatkustus-ryhmat/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML,  like Gecko) Version/16.2 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"

xx.xxx.xxx.xx3 - - [19/May/2023:23:37:22 +0300] "POST /tyomatkustus-ryhmat/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8979 "https://www.MYDOMAIN.fi/tyomatkustus-ryhmat/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.2 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"

xx.xxx.xxx.xx3 - - [20/May/2023:13:05:29 +0300] "POST /tyomatkustus-ryhmat/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8979 "https://www.MYDOMAIN.fi/tyomatkustus-ryhmat/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.2 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"

xxx.xx.xxx.xx4 - - [21/May/2023:00:29:04 +0300] "POST /tyomatkustus-ryhmat/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8979 "https://www.MYDOMAIN.fi/tyomatkustus-ryhmat/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.2 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
```

Has anyone ever experienced anything similar / have any idea what might be causing this problem / is there anything that can be done to prevent this?